# typedef with function this is asked but couldnt understand?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

HI i am unable to figure out how function pointer is typedef in below code .please can anyone explain

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 typedef int(*fp)(int,int) ; this is typedef with function pointer i m unable to figure out?
 int sum (int,int);
 int main()
{
    fp p,q; // p, q become function pointer too how?
    p=sum;
    printf("%d\n",p(20,10));
}
 int sum(int i,int j)
{
    return(i+j);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's not much to understand. You define a new type int(*fp)(int, int). This is not a function pointer, but a function pointer type. Compare fp to float, int, or any other primitive types. Then you declare p and q of the above mentioned type and assign to p the function sum which is of the same type (implicit).

Answer (score 0):

Function has signature

```
int NAME(int ,int );
```

so pointer to it is

```
int (*NAME_OF_POINTER)(int, int);
```

To predict long names define new type for function pointer

```
typedef int (*NEW_TYPE_NAME)(int, int);
```

And use it. So instead of

```
int (*myVar)(int, int) = sum;
```

You can write now

```
NEW_TYPE_NAME myVar = sum;
```